# Concise way to invoke an event safely in .Net

Tags: c#, events

Is there a concise way to safely invoke events in C#.Net. I would like to safely deal with no subscribers and exceptions subscribers might throw...

I kinda want a TryInvoke method on Delegate..ideally where I could pass an exception handler too. I am in .Net 3.5 so don't have extension methods...

Anyway here is the boilerplate I typically use.

```
    void fireListChanged(List<string> paths)
    {             
        try
        {
            if (ListChanged != null)
            {
                ListChanged(paths);
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            m_output.write(ex);
        }
    }

    public event ListStringChangedDlgt ListChanged;
```

Comment: Extension methods are only unavailable in .Net 1.0, 1.1, and 2.0 so you should be fine using them.

Comment: FYI, extension methods were introduced in .NET 3.0 but they aren't an appropriate solution for this issue.

Comment: C# 3.0 that shipped with .Net 3.5 does have extension methods.

Comment: BTW, if there are more subscribers to the event and one of them throws an exception, the rest of them won't be called with your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the `= delegate {}` pattern. The bonus compared to your solution is that it's thread safe.

```
void fireListChanged(List<string> paths)
{             
    try
    {
            ListChanged(paths);
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        m_output.write(ex);
    }
}

public event ListStringChangedDlgt ListChanged = delegate {};
```

I also recommend that you use `EventHandler` or `EventHandler<YourEventArgClass>` as delegate for the event.

Comment: does this also fix the issue that if one of the handlers invoked throws an exception? Otherwise you will have to foreach() anyway.

Comment: I was reading up on C# events from that one excellent CodeProject page. Around the end of section 7, it briefly mentions foreaching over the `GetInvocationList()` of an event, so you can raise all the events, even if one throws an unhandled exception. Is doing this fairly common in production code? It feels somewhat unwieldly to do for *every* event.